# Adding delimiters to a text file using python

Tags: python, etl

I have recently started my job as an ETL Developer and as a part of my exercise, I am extracting data from a text file containing raw data. My raw data looks like this as shown in the image.
[My Raw Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YE76K.png)

Now I want to add delimiters to my data file. Basically after every line, I want to add a comma (`,`). My code in Python looks like this.

```
with open ('new_locations.txt', 'w') as output:
with open('locations.txt', 'r') as input:
    for line in input:
        new_line = line+','
        output.write(new_line)
```

where `new_locations.txt` is the output text file, `locations.txt` is the raw data.

However, it throws me error all the time.

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 3724: character maps to

Where exactly am I going wrong?

> Note: The characters in raw data are not all ASCII characters. Some are Latin characters as well.

Comment: Can you read the entire file without these errors?

Comment: @DanielLee No I am unable to read the entire file. I am only able to read it till ASCII characters are present. Once the other characters start, they throw an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open a file in python 3 in "text" mode then reading and writing convert the bytes in the file to python (unicode) strings. The default encoding is platform dependent, but is usually UTF-8.

If you file uses latin-1 encoding, you should open with

```
with open('locations.txt', 'r', encoding='latin_1') as input
```

You should probably also do this with the output if you want the output also to be in latin-1.

In the longer term, you should probably consider converting all your data to a unicode format in the data files.

Answer (score 0):

So when you write to file you need to encode it before writing. If you google that you will find ton of results.

Here is how it can be done :

```
output.write(new_line.encode('utf-8'))# or ascii
```

You can also ask to ignore which can't be converted but that wil cause loss of charachter and may not be the desired output, here is how that will be done :

```
output.write(new_line.encode('ascii','ignore'))# or 'utf-8'
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. However I have a follow up question to this. 'utf-8' didn't work for me. 'Latin-1' did. Now a raw data could be a mixture of different characters. How to make this completely generic? I don't want to differentitate between any character.

Comment: so latin-1 encoding will have extra support for charachter not supported in utf-8 or ascii, it won't be that it will change all char to latin-1, only to those which aren't supported. James above has a better way to do from what I suggested.